# A python program that reads numbers and stops when you enter 'done' using try and except

Tags: python, exception, input, error-handling, data-conversion

I tried writing a program that reads numbers using a loop, evaluates the total numbers, prints it and stops when you type done using try and except.

```
initiator = True
myList = []

while initiator:
    try:
        userIn = int(input('Enter any number >>  '))
        myList.append(userIn)
        print(myList)

    except ValueError:
        if str(userIn):
            if userIn == 'done':
                pass
            average = eval(myList)
            print(average)
            initiator = False

        else:
            print('Wrong input!\nPlease try again')
            continue
```

Comment: And so what is your actual question?  If this code isn't working as you want, you need to explain.  Are you getting errors, or unexpected output?

Comment: Stopping by to say - [don't use eval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/4935162). Not sure why it's in this code in the first place. Edit: okay, it doesn't do what you think it does. See Barmar's answer

Comment: It says: average = eval(myList) TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object

Comment: What did you think calling `eval()` on a list would do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `int()` raises an exception, it doesn't set `userIn`, so you can't compare `userIn` with `done`.

You should separate reading the input and callint `int()`.

```
while True:
    try:
        userIn = input('Enter any number >>  ')
        num = int(userIn)
        myList.append(num)
        print(myList)

    except ValueError:
        if userIn == 'done':
            break
        else:
            print('Wrong input!\nPlease try again')

average = sum(myList) / len(myList)
print(average)
```

`eval()` is not the correct way to get the average of a list. Use `sum()` to add up the list elements, and divide by the length to get the average.